# How long for tank to drain completely?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

[image]

I tried integrating it:

$\frac{2}{5}H^{5/2} = -ct + k$,    where $k$ is the constant from integration

$H = \sqrt[5]{\frac{25}{4}(k-ct)^2}$

When $t = 0$, $H = \sqrt[5]{\frac{25}{4}k^2}$

When $t = 1$, $h = \sqrt[5]{\frac{25}{4}(k-c)^2}$

$H/h = 2$

Hence  $2 = \sqrt[5]{k^2(k-c)^2}$

I'm stuck.

Comment: not sure what that root is, so I'll avoid editing it for now.

Comment: square root cube root etc. thats root of 5 haha

Comment: $t=0,h=H$ gives you $k$. $t=1,h=\frac{1}{2}H$ gives you $c$. Then putting $h=0$ you get $t=\frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{5}{2}}}=1.2147$ hrs.

Comment: Please note that  \sqrt[5]{xyz} gives $ \sqrt[5]{xyz}$ in this site's markup. Please edit appropriately, it's difficult to see exactly what the problem is without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dh}{dt}=-\frac{c}{h^\frac{3}{2}} => h^\frac{3}{2}dh = -c dt => \frac{2}{5}h^\frac{5}{2} = -ct + const => h(t)=H-\frac{5}{2}(ct)^\frac{2}{5}$. If you know that for $t=1$ (hr) $h(1) = \frac{1}{2} H$, you can find c, and, setting $H=\frac{5}{2}(ct)^\frac{2}{5}$, find $t$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi what happened to the const

Comment: $const$ is an arbitrary constant satisfying $h(0) = H$